# CentOS 7 server rebooted itself into rescue mode - how can I find out why?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, centos7, diskmanagement, smart

I've switched it back to regular boot and it seems to boot up fine.

So why did it reboot?

Running "last" doesn't even show a log OF a reboot.  What does that suggest?

When I try "smartctl -a /dev/sda1" I get "SMART support is: Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability."

Seems odd for what claim to be 15k HP drives.  Maybe it's due to the RAID setup though?

It's a oneprovider.com box, and came described as "3x 4TB HW RAID 5".

Help?

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know, only a hardware problem can do this and if the machine rebooted, it might very well be a hard drive issue. Do you have a RAID card in there?

Comment: "Probably".  It's a budget box so details are thin on the ground.  How would I find out what make/model etc the RAID is?

Comment: I hate to say it, but you would have to open it up. That would probably be your better bet anyway. Opening it up exposes you to whatever else may be wrong with it. Gives you an opportunity to see it in action. Almost kind of like doing a biopsy  :)

Comment: 16hr round trip rules that out!

Comment: I got into ILO and determined that it's an HP ProLiant DL120 G7 with three HP MB4000ECVJK drives, but I couldn't see any information about the RAID in there. lspci tells me "Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array G6 controllers". dmidecode didn't appear to say anything about RAID/drives at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens in this instance, the datacenter had rebooted the box due to abuse notifications, which were based on previous activity of the IP address before I'd got it...

Answer (score 0):

you can get some information about your raid with lspci and dmidecode, knowing the model of your server and having some information about the hardware configuration will help you to define the raid controller you use! If you send those data, we may try to find a solution with you :)

Cheers,
Julian

Comment: I got into ILO and determined that it's an HP ProLiant DL120 G7 with three HP MB4000ECVJK drives, but I couldn't see any information about the RAID in there.  lspci tells me "Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array G6 controllers".  dmidecode didn't appear to say anything about RAID/drives at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [kernel crash dump](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kdump/kdump.txt) : you will be able to analyse the dump after the next reboot to see what happens if it is due to a kernel panic.